# Translation of polygon after rotation

Tags: python-3.x, geometry, tkinter-canvas

I have two functions one that performs a rotation in 2D canvas item (polygon) and another that translate the 'robot'. The move is like this:

[image: robot movement].

If a rotation is performed the movement should be like this:

[image: robot movement after rotation].

Here the functions:

```
def rotation(self, i):
    if i == '+':
        if self.angle == 360:
            self.angle = 0.0
        self.angle += 1
        delta = radians(1)
    elif i == '-':
        if self.angle == 0:
            self.angle = 360.0
        self.angle -= 1
        delta = -radians(1)
    x0, y0 = self.center[0], self.center[1]
    tmp = list()
    pts = self.polygon
    for i in range(0, len(pts), 2):
        xa, ya = pts[i], pts[i + 1]
        xl, yl = xa - x0, ya - y0
        xll, yll = cos(delta) * xl + sin(delta) * yl, -sin(delta) * xl + cos(delta) * yl
        xr, yr = xll + x0, yll + y0
        tmp.append(xr)
        tmp.append(yr)
    self.polygon = tmp.copy()
    self.arena.coords(self.item_canvas, self.polygon)

def move_polygon(self, x, y, switch=False):
    tmp = self.polygon
    for i in range(0, len(tmp), 2):
        if not switch:
            tmp[i] += cos(radians(self.angle)) * x * 5
            tmp[i + 1] += -sin(radians(self.angle)) * y * 5
        else:
            tmp[i] += -sin(radians(self.angle)) * x * 5
            tmp[i + 1] += cos(radians(self.angle)) * y * 5
        print('x:{} y:{}'.format(cos(radians(self.angle)), -sin(radians(self.angle))))
    self.polygon = tmp.copy()
    self.update_polygon()

def move(self, dir):
    if dir == 'f':
        x, y = cos(radians(self.angle)), sin(radians(self.angle))
        self._move_polygon(x, y)
    if dir == 'b':
        x, y = -cos(radians(self.angle)), -sin(radians(self.angle))
        self._move_polygon(x, y)
    if dir == 'l':
        x, y = -sin(radians(self.angle)), -cos(radians(self.angle))
        self._move_polygon(x, y, True)
    if dir == 'r':
        x, y = sin(radians(self.angle)), cos(radians(self.angle))
        self._move_polygon(x, y, True)
```

The idea is passing the variation of x and y in function of the angle to the translation function (move_polygon). When the angle is zero the movement is right (only in the 1st and 3th quadrant, with directions reversed...).

I know that I need to add the x and y offset to perform the translation but the relation with the angle, center and the rotated axis is confusing and frustrating. So I need help to understand the math and the right way to perform this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So robot has own direction `self.angle` and you want to move robot in this direction, in back direction, and shift it (like strafe in shooter games?) left and right?

In this case you need to change signs in `move`:

```
 if dir == 'l':
      x, y = sin(radians(self.angle)), -cos(radians(self.angle))
      self._move_polygon(x, y, True)
 if dir == 'r':
      x, y = -sin(radians(self.angle)), cos(radians(self.angle))
```

But why do you apply `cos` and `sin` factors **again** inside `move_polygon`?? It seems you just need to update coordinates with provided shifts (using velocity coefficient) like this:

```
 tmp[i] += x * 5   
 tmp[i+1] += y * 5
```

Also remove `True` as `switch` parameters

Comment: Ok. It works fine. After switching the signs and removing the unnecessary sin/cos factors from the move_polygon the robot move correctly in the first quadrant angles (0º >= self.angle <= 90º) and **wrongly** in the third and forth. In the second the controls direction are inverted.

Comment: BTW - is your coordinate system left-handed or right-handed?

Comment: Here [the functions](https://pastebin.com/hj9NTtZM) @MBo. The controls are reversed. I have to understand the angle relationship with them ... I know I'll have to swap the signal or the inputs (x, y) at some point according to the angle I think.
-
I believe it's left-handed. I'm using tkinter, how do I check this out?

Comment: Just log or print data: make angle 45 and log x,y. make angles 135, 225, 315 and log again. Misunderstanding of system handness might broke relation between your "left" and screen "left" too.

Comment: In mathematical system OX direction is right, OY direction is left, angles go from OX in CCW direction. In "MM_TEXT" system OY direction is down, angles go in CW direction. There are also screen systems with angle counted from vertical axis. Where is (0,0) point at your screen?

Comment: The figure is centered in (350.0, 350.0). [Here](https://pastebin.com/pAeSKSmD) the logs. The origin is in upper-left.

Comment: Your system is left-handed, angles go clockwise. So signs should be reversed in my answer - I corrected them. But I don't understand - why x remains the same here: `key:s dir:b x:350.0 y:350.0 ang:0.0º` and for other "back" moves

Comment: Ok. I double-checked and I was miss clicking or something... _key:s dir:b x:345.0 y:350.0 ang:0.0º_ . Thx a lot sir.

Comment: I see `if dir == 't':` while t is not defined and so on